# Serial port ReadFile receives repeated data

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, serial-port

I am working on a multi threading program to read and write to a serial port. If I test my application with Putty everything is fine. But when I test it with the created .exe-file, it doesn't work. (I start the program in VS2017 and then the .exe file)

E.g.: My input: "Test", the output in the other window: "Teeeeeeeeeeeessssssssssttttttt".

My code to send the data:

```
void SendDataToPort()
{
for (size_t i = 0; i <= strlen(line); i++) // loop through the array until 
 every letter has been sent
{
    try
    {
        if (i == strlen(line))  // If ever letter has been sent                 
        {                       // end it with a new line
            c = '\n';           // a new line
        }
        else
        {
            c = line[i];
        }
        WriteFile(serialHandle, &c, 1, &dwBytesWrite, NULL); // Send letter to serial port
    }
    catch (const exception&)
    {
        cout << "Error while writing.";
    }
}
cout << endl << "Sent." << endl;
}
```

In the array "line" I have the input from the user.

My code to read the data:

```
int newLineCounter = 0;
unsigned char tmp;
while (!endCurrentRead)
{
    ReadFile(hSerial, &tmp, 1, &bytesRead, NULL); // Get new letter

    if (tmp != '\n')
    {
        newLineCounter = 0;
        if (tmp >= 32 && tmp <= 126)
        {
            output += tmp; // Add current letter to the output
        }
    }
    else
    {
        newLineCounter++;
        if (newLineCounter < 2) // If there are more than 2 '\n' it doesn't write it down
        {
            output += tmp;
        }
        else if (newLineCounter == 2)
        {
            Print(output);
            output = receiverName;
            endCurrentRead = true;
        }
    }
}
```

After that I write the data down with the Print(output) function:

```
cout << output << endl;
```

How I create the Handle File:

```
serialHandle = CreateFile(LcomPort, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
```

Why is this happening and why is this only happening when I test it with the .exe-file and not with Putty?

Comment: You don't check either the return value of `ReadFile` or `bytesRead`.

Comment: and what Davis said **is _very_ important** because you can get a return value telling you that **nothing was read** (receive buffer was empty and we didn't wait for new data) and your code wouldn't notice and would assume it got the same data as before, thereforeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee....

Comment: @DavidSchwartz how can I check the return value?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I tried: if (ReadFile(hSerial, &tmp, 1, &bytesRead, NULL)) . But it is still not working. Doesn't it return true when there is something to read and if not false?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl `ReadFile()` returns a BOOL, not an HRESULT. If failed, an error code integer (still not an HRESULT) is returned by `GetLastError()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: you're right :) my bad, I didn't read that on MSDN myself, just picked msd link from google and trusted my memory about return value.

Comment: @User987123: sorry about that, I should have reviewed [that MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx) myself before writing. ReadFile only returns true/false telling you about errors. However, there's `lpNumberOfBytesRead` and `lpOverlapped` out-parameters, which will be written to by the ReadFile and those can tell you how many bytes were actually read. You already seem to have (`&bytesRead`) and your code seems to not use overlapped operations, so why don't you try checking if bytesRead is >0 ?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl So I have to check if `bytesRead` got incremented before I read the data?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I tried this:

`while (!endCurrentRead)
 {
  if (bytesRead > 0)
  {
   ReadFile(hSerial, &tmp, 1, &bytesRead, NULL); // Get new letter
...
}
}`

What should I change that it works?

Comment: before? how would you want to check if your box was full, if you haven't yet gone to the post office to collect it? can you read the future? calling ReadFile will write to that `bytesRead` variable. You have to check it **afterwards**

Comment: @quetzalcoatl thank you so much. It is working now. I hope you have a nice day :)

Comment: glad to help :) it's great you wrote a follow-up response, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the help of **@quetzalcoatl**, I was able to solve the problem. I have to check if the `bytesRead` are bigger then 0.

Solution:

```
int newLineCounter = 0;
DWORD dwCommModemStatus;
unsigned char tmp;
while (!endCurrentRead)
{
    ReadFile(hSerial, &tmp, 1, &bytesRead, NULL); // Get new letter
    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        if (tmp != '\n')
        {
            newLineCounter = 0;
            if (tmp >= 32 && tmp <= 126)
            {
                output += tmp; // Add current letter to the output
            }
        }
        else
        {
            output += tmp;
            Print(output);
            output = receiverName;
            endCurrentRead = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You ought to pay more attention to the reason why ReadFile() failed.  Looks to me that the timeout is set excessively low, review your SetCommTimeouts() call.  Or add it if you forgot to use it.

Comment: @HansPassant I have timeouts in my code, but I haven't added it to my question/answer. But thank you for the advise.